# Import modules in Jupyter Notebook - Path

Tags: python, import, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have the following structure in my python project:

```
BASE_DIRECTORY
¦- data
¦- notebooks
¦  \
¦   ***here are the jupyter notebooks***
¦   __init__.py
¦   analysis.ipynb
¦
¦- src
¦  \
¦   ***here are further modules***
¦   __init__.py
¦   configuration.py
¦
```

I would like to import class Config() from configuration.py into a jupyter notebook analysis.ipynb.

I tried:

```
from ..src.configuration import Config
```

but that gives me a ValueError:

```
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

Can someone direct how to achieve this? I would prefer to work with relative paths rather than with changing PATH variables.

I feel there are some specifics about Jupyter that I am not aware of, e.g. it seems to be harder to refer to the current path.

Comment: Maybe it is because there is no __init.py__ in your root folder, but not sure. Check it out

Comment: referring to the work directory is indeed involved (not to say non-deterministic?) in jupyter, [see discussion here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/10123). working with the `sys.path` variable is the best/only way I could recommend, and @oppy's answer works for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I saw that you said that you do not want to alter the path variables, but using sys to do this gives a solution:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('..')

from src.configuration import Config
```